#REF! for GETPIVOTDATA - Trying to just get the sum of a column

Hello. Tryin to get the sum of the allowed data column.
I use =GETPIVOTDATA("Allowed ",$A$11), but still get a !REF.

Looks like your formula has a space? are you sure there is a space after the word Allowed  in the pivot as well? This is your formula try to remove the space and see what happens : =GETPIVOTDATA("Allowed ",$A$11)

Yes, there is supposed to be a space.

You could try this may be it should work: =GETPIVOTDATA("Claim Number",$A$11,Field,"Allowed ")

Does your pivot table have a grand total for the rows? Is your formula the same for all of the columns? The way getpivotdata works is it's trying to find the intersection of your conditions, so with no claim number it looks to the Grand Total, not necessarily taking the sum of that column manually.

I suspect it to be a few things, though I can't confirm them without more context from your table.
My first guess is that you may be missing a Grand Total from the bottom and the GETPIVOTDATA when it's not filtered for the fields in the table will look at the grand total instead of adding up the values in the field given. You can see this effect in the image below where the same formula yields and error with not reference to the grand total existing.
My second guess is that although the formula has a space the field itself actually does not so it's not actually seeing the field properly. In my image you'll see the formulatext looks at "Allowed" even though the table is displaying "Sum of Allowed". I imagine the name is a duplicate so you added the trailing space so it appears a certain way but works; however the original column name is still how it is called into the pivot.
Below you can see a simple recreation of your table with and without the column and a formula referencing the total as well as the non-display name. I would ensure you have both a grand total to reference as well as confirming you're referencing the correct field name.

